# Outputting Json format from Sql select query

Tags: json

Quite a newbie with SQL, and gradually getting used to the Management Studio

Ideally, I would like to have the output in JSON forma, and emailed to a specific mailbox.

I would like the above scheduled using the Service Agent

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ok,  so I now have a SQL view which I need to email out in its entirety, as an attachment in JSON format. Hope this helps